# how to understand the size of windowing in toeplitz?

Tags: matlab

I want to remove noise from a noisy signal, the noisy signal contain 3 frequency components, i converted the noisy signal vector to matrix with toeplitz then removed noise with SVD, now i dont khow how to covert this matrix to vector, i tried reshape but its length wasnt the same az my original signal to compare the origenal signal and denoised signal and also my teacher told me in this program when i convert the vector to matrix with toeplitz, the size of window be fit with the lowest frequency of the signal and i dont know how to do this? my program:

```
f1 = 5 ;f2= 10 ;f3 = 15 ;
t =0:0.01:2.5;
y1 = sin(2*pi*f1*t);y2 = sin(2*pi*f2*t) ;y3 = sin(2*pi*f3*t) ;
y = y1 + y2 + y3  ;  
snr=10;
x = awgn(y,snr); 
x1 = toeplitz(x);
[U,S,V] = svd(x1);
A=zeros(251,251);
S(90:251,90:251)=A(90:251,90:251);
x2=U*S*V';
```

Comment: Next time format your question properly

Comment: Note that your `x2` is also approximately Toeplitz (check with imagesc(x2)). So maybe you just need its first row? `result = x2(1,:);`

Comment: i got the answer thank you, for my question format i'm sorry my english is not good and i dont know how to format good and what x2(1,:) means?

Comment: `x2(1,:)` is the first row of matrix `x2`

Comment: It sounds as if you're a student. It might be worth understanding the basics of MATLAB and looking at some tutorials (e.g. http://www.mathworks.co.uk/academia/student_center/tutorials/index.html) before attempting more advanced stuff without really understanding what you're doing.

Comment: yes i'm beginner but i can't access mathwork because it is filtered in our country.About the size of window how can i fit it with the lowest frequnsy in the signal?